# AVAudioPlayer will not play when device is locked

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I am using `AVAudioPlayer` in my application. When I select a song it plays, but my problem is, it is not playing when the device gets locked.

Comment: you solved ur problem or not ? please let me know.. i am also facing same issue..

Answer (score 3):

You need to read [Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4) in Apple's documentation. If you set the `UIBackgroundModes` key in you app's `Info.plist` to `audio`, audio will keep playing while backgrounded.

See the sections *Declaring the Background Tasks You Support* and *Playing Background Audio* in the aforementioned documentation.

Answer (score 2):

All we need to make music play in the background with AVAudioPlayer by two step:

Step 1: Choose Project -> Capabilities -> Enable Background Modes -> Select Audio Mode

Step 2: Use this code:

```
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"demo" withExtension:@"mp3"];
avSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
[avSound setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[avSound prepareToPlay];
[avSound setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[avSound setVolume:1.0];
```

Note that with this line the music can start even if the app was in the background:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Comment: `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` really did the trick! Do you know if there are some limitations using it? Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge it is not possible to play sound when device locked. Can't you just disallow device to lock and alive apps active always until user close it manually ?

Comment: Plenty of alarms do start audio after being locked for a long time.