# Screen Lock & sound stop iPhone dev (FLASH CS5.5)

Tags: iphone, flash

I'm trying to create iPhone apps using Flash CS5.5 and I have a doubt. I just created a simple app which plays a long sound (more than 5 min).

When the phone auto-locks, my sounds stop. If I unlock the phone, my audio resumes.

What could I do to avoid the lock, or don't interrupt the sound when the device auto-locks?

Answer (score 1):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES]

set this for stoping lock the screen.

Answer (score 1):

set this for stoping to lock the screen in ActionScript 3.0,

Import classes:

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication 
import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
```

Don't forget to check

> WAKE_LOCK

in the permission in AIR settings,

[image]

If you want normal then use,

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the lock, you can look at idleTimerDisabled of UIApplication property. Or to run the sound even if the screen is locked, check the link below:

[AVAudioPlayer will not play when device is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516954/avaudioplayer-will-not-play-when-device-is-locked)